# Firebase initialization gives app/duplicate-app error

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

For my blog, I'm allowing users to input their email and then adding said email to a firebase database so I can send mass emails to those who have subscribed when I make a new post. I tested my code on my machine and it worked just fine.

First, I included the firebase `<script>` tag, then I include my own script tag, which links to a file that includes the following at the top:

```
var config = {
    apiKey: "...",
    authDomain: "...",
    databaseURL: "...",
    projectId: "...",
    storageBucket: "...",
    messagingSenderId: "..."
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

This works fine on my machine, but I pushed the files to GitHub, where my blog is being hosted, and when I run `firebase.initializeApp(config)` it doesn't work any more.  It gives me an error, `Firebase: Firebase App named '[DEFAULT]' already exists (app/duplicate-app)`. I don't know exactly how to fix this.  I've already tried giving `firebase.initializeApp()` a second argument, which would be a randomly generated ID that is saved in cookies, but that didn't work either; I got the same error.

This is all being done on the frontend, since GitHub Pages doesn't support backend.  Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

That error message means something on the page already called `firebase.initializeApp()` prior to the invocation that generated that error.  None of us here are going to have the visibility into your entire site to know if and how this could happen, you're going to have to start digging through the components of your site to debug this.  Maybe even set up a debugger breakpoint inside initializeApp() to trap when it's first been called, and examine the stack to see where it's at.

If there's some other component that's initializing the default instance of Firebase, and that is legit for the page, you can work around that by initializing a non-default instance by giving it a name (passing the second argument of [initializeApp()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase#.initializeApp)), holding its reference, and passing that around to get alternative instances of database, auth, storage, etc.

Comment: There's literally only one JavaScript file, and that's at the top of it, and it's still throwing the error...

Comment: Well, did you try the debugging I suggested?  That error definitely means what I say it means.

Comment: I don't know how to "set up a debugger breakpoint," so no, I did not try that... could you perhaps give me some guidance?

Comment: It sounds like it's time to do some google searches for a tutorial.

Comment: I literally don't even know what to google, dude.  You're not exactly being helpful.

Comment: How about javascript debugging [insert your browser name]?

Comment: That's far too general to ever be of help to me.  My problem is firebase-specific.  Why do you think I came to SO in the first place?

Comment: What I'm saying is that there's not enough information here to diagnose what's going wrong.  All anyone can tell you is what that message means and what you can do to deal with it.  If you are willing to go back and forth over some period of time with a support agent, you can file a support issue, but that process may not be fast.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/

Comment: I'm just going to try that.  Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not exactly sure why it was giving me a `duplicate-app` error, but it turns out I forgot to `firebase.signInAnonymously()`. Adding that line after the `initializeApp()` but before `onAuthStateChange` fixed the problem.  I feel like a fool, but I figured I'd put the answer here and post it in case some other similarly absent-minded person makes the same mistake. :P